# how do i validate already table in mysql schema?

Tags: mysql, flyway

Could not validate table exists in MySQL.

Tried below query but no output.

```
if !(select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='sy_code')
```

Comment: no output mean that not exist bro

Answer (score 0):

To see the schema of a table, use query

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

To see all the existing table in our database, use query

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'your_db'
```